# Add more controls at Run Time

Tags: gui-design, controls

I am developing customized schedule generator application for which I need to design User Interface. This UI will have an option to select Date, Time and number of hours. This is simply possible by adding date/time picker control and domain control. However, there can be more than one session per day and there can be multiple dates. So I want to allow user to add more input field on UI whenever required. I want a way to give best user experience than the traditional way to give `Add` button to add one more set of controls:

[Date] [Time] [No Of Hours]  [Add more]

[Date] [Time] [No Of Hours]

[Date] [Time] [No Of Hours]

[Date] [Time] [No Of Hours]

[Date] [Time] [No Of Hours]

[Generate]

Any suggestion on improving user experience in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding a new set of fields on user click what if a new field appeared after filling in the date and time. Then providing users with the ability to remove a schedule on hover of that section.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8b0US.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>